# How to call MmGetPhysicalMemoryRanges in driver to get memory range?

Tags: windows, memory, kernel, driver

I am writing a driver in which i want the exact range of RAM. I came to know about memory manager routines inside windows kernel. I am planning to include MmGetPhysicalMemoryRanges routine in my driver also to get memory range.
I don't know how to add these routines into driver..
Anyone please tell me how to write this routine??What is its syntax???

Comment: [As per the documentation:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff554435(v=vs.85).aspx) "The following routines are reserved for system use. Do not use them in your driver."

Comment: I am using these routines for my project. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NTKERNELAPI

PPHYSICAL_MEMORY_RANGE

MmGetPhysicalMemoryRanges (

VOID

);
```

Where PHYSICAL_MEMORY_RANGE is:

```
typedef struct _PHYSICAL_MEMORY_RANGE {

PHYSICAL_ADDRESS BaseAddress;

LARGE_INTEGER NumberOfBytes;

} PHYSICAL_MEMORY_RANGE, *PPHYSICAL_MEMORY_RANGE;
```